# Clustering a distance matrix with k-medoids

Tags: clustering, partitioning, k-medoids

For a symmetric distance matrix that I want to cluster, I performed several cluster algorithms:

1. MDS into k-Means
2. DBSCAN
3. OPTICS
4. k-Medoids (the one I'm having trouble with)

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to determine the optimal number of clusters (for a distance matrix) without aplying MDS on the data beforehand to analyize by Elbow method, Silhouette method or Calinsky-Harabasz criterion. I came up with the idea of doing a *ESS vs. k* plot for several k to evaluate the minimum value as the "optimal k", but I'm not certain if this is actually correct.

Is the "Error Sum of Squares of the whole clustering" from k-medoids a more or less acceptable way to determine the optimal number of clusters?

Comment: It would be very nice and to everyone's interest if you leave a couple of phrases about each approach. For example, what hides behind pt 1 method.

Comment: @ttnphns Of course, what I did in the first methods was to set a coordinate representation in low dimension of my original distance matrix so I can perform k-means into my data, since k-means only allows X,Y,Z type of data. 
In the case of DBSCAN and OPTICS, I have no problem in creating clusters because the only requirement is to adjust my Eps and Min-Pts parameters to create them.
Hopefully this helps to better understand what I'm trying to achieve and thanks for the feedback by the way!